# Arch Linux: distortions during fast changes on screen (vsync)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, video, window-manager, i3

I am using Arch linux with i3wm on my Lenovo x390 yoga notebook. I am experiencing weird glitch during fast changes on screen (videos, games, cursor movement).

The glitch are horizontal lines dividing two slightly shifted images. It is caused by refreshing only part of a screen. There is an image of same issue:

[image: vsync glitch]

I do not experience that big distortion like on image but it is very noticeable and annoying.
It is not dependent on any program. I experience it everywhere.

How can I diagnose and fix this issue ?

Session type:

```bsh
john@arch-thinkpad ~> echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
tty
```

**PS:** If you need more information just tell me in comments and I will quickly provide it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file with this content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"

  Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

and rebooting.